# Does the twisted product $K^{\mathbb{C}}\times_{Z(k)^{\mathbb{C}}} X^k$ have a natural Kähler or sympletic structure?

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Let $K$ be a  connected  compact Lie group, and suppose that  $(X,J,\omega)$ is  a compact Kähler manifold  on which the group $K$
acts holomorphically such that the group $K$ preserves the
Kähler form and is Hamiltonian with momentum map $\mu: X \rightarrow  \mathfrak{k}^*$.

The fixed point set $X^k:=\{x\in X|k.x=x\}$ is a Kähler manifold for any $k\in K.$

Denote  $Z(k)$ by the centralizer of $k\in K$.

As a sympletic manifold, the tuple $(X^k,Z(k),\omega|_{X^k},\mu|_{X^k})$  is Hamiltonian with momentum map $\mu|_{X^k}: X^k \rightarrow {\text{Lie}(Z(k))}^*$,
and we can extend the $Z(k)$-action on $X^k$ to the complexification $Z_{\mathbb{C}}(k)$.

My Question is the following:

Does the twisted product $K^{\mathbb{C}}\times_{Z(k)^{\mathbb{C}}} X^k$ have a natural Kähler structure,
where $Z(k)^{\mathbb{C}}$ is  the complexified Lie group of the centralizer $Z(k)$ of $k\in K$?